# Подскажите, как нарисовать шахматную доску с фигурами на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нарисовать шахматную доску, Строки должны нумероваться числами от 1 до 8, столбцы – латинскими буквами A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H. И поставить на нее фигуры. На чистом JavaScript?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вам еще и фигуры рисовать надо :Р

Comment: Фигуры через юникод можно, я думаю